# Spatstat: Cluster processes for interactions in marked point patterns?

Tags: spatstat

I am trying to identify clustering patterns between different marks using point process models.

Multitype Strauss is the only model I have found thus far which can compare interactions between different marks. Is there a clustering model that can be used on mullti-type point patterns

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately. The `spatstat` model-fitting function `kppm` does not currently support fitting multitype cluster processes to multitype point pattern data. This is on the "to do" list.

Other packages such as `binspp` and `lgcp` may do what you want.